# When using "Add as New Query" on a list comlumn in Power BI, will it trigger another round trip to the server?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have connected PowerBI to a REST endpoint, where some of the data are lists.

When I use the option "Add as New Query", I wonder if this will trigger another roundtrip to the REST endpoint, when loading data (or is Power BI smart enough to know, that multipole queries are now using the same endpoint)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding it as a new query will create a copy of the M code you created so far in a new query, including the connection to the source, therefore it should make a new call to the data source.

If you don't want to make multiple calls to the endpoint use the "Reference" function, it allows you to reference an existing table in its last state.
You may need to:

1. load the source table once
2. reference it in the other N queries
3. don't load the source table in the model (toggle "Enable Load")